# Jquery Timepicker for IE

Tags: php, jquery, timepicker

I am php developer..i need to add jquery timepicker for field in form.i use this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {

                        $("#time2").timePicker({
                            startTime : "08.00", // Using string. Can take string or Date object.
                        endTime : new Date(0, 0, 0, 23, 30, 0), // Using Date object.
                        show24Hours : false,
                        separator : ':',
                        step : 15,
                    });

                });

</script>
```

my textfield

```
<input type="text" id="time2" name="pickuptime" class="txt-timepiker" size="10" value="08:00 AM" id="tooltipdest" readonly="readonly"/>
```

this is a working on chrome, firefox and IE10. but it is not working for IE8. how to fix it.can anyone help me?